# Angular view not updating when model changed in socket.io event callback

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sockets

I have a problem that I update this.customers in my controller but it does not update in the view

The relevant functions are:

//support.js

```
(function(){
'use strict';

var SupportCtrl = function($state, SocketFactory){
  this.user = "Will"
  this.customers = ['will','tom']
  SocketFactory.on('queue', function(queue){
    console.log(queue)
    this.customers = queue
  })
}

angular
  .module('support',[])
  .config(['$stateProvider', function($stateProvider){
    $stateProvider
      .state('support',{
        url: '/support',
        templateUrl: 'modules/support/support.html',
        controllerAs: 'support',
        controller: 'SupportCtrl'
      })
  }])

  .controller('SupportCtrl', [
    '$state',
    'SocketFactory',
    SupportCtrl
  ])

})()
```

//socketService.js

```
(function(){
'use strict';

var SocketFactory = function($rootScope){
  var socket = io.connect();
  return {
    on: function (eventName, callback) {
      socket.on(eventName, function () {  
        var args = arguments;
        console.log($rootScope)
        $rootScope.$apply(function () {
          callback.apply(socket, args);
        });
      });
    },
    emit: function (eventName, data, callback) {
      socket.emit(eventName, data, function () {
        var args = arguments;
        $rootScope.$apply(function () {
          if (callback) {
            callback.apply(socket, args);
          }
        });
      })
    }
  };
};

angular
  .module('ecomApp')
  .service('SocketFactory', [
    SocketFactory,
  ]);

})();
```

//support.html

```
<div>
  <li ng-repeat="(roomNameKey, roomName) in support.customers">{{roomNameKey}}: {{roomName}}</li>
</div>
```

**Diagnosis**

this.customers prints to the screen 
0: will
1: tom
But on the Socket 'queue' event the object:

```
{roomName: "ikp3f"}
```

is successfully console.logged but the angular view is not updated

I suspect this might have to do with the digest cycle and $apply() - do I need to call $apply() in my SupportCtrl?

Thanks for the help

Comment: Are you posting entire `socketService.js` content?

Comment: Don't know if this is the problem, but it seems as if your support module should be dependent on your ecomApp module, but I'd think you'd be seeing a different error.

Comment: You are specifying array which should contain dependency names in service definition. Just remove the array from `.service('SocketFactory', SocketFactory)`. With this `$injector` will try to guess your parameters based on their names.

Comment: @PavelHoral - that fixes the $rootScope issue - thank you! Now to get the view to update...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are invoking callback with

```
callback.apply(socket, args);
```

"this" in the callback will be the socket, not the controller.

Try

```
var SupportCtrl = function($state, SocketFactory){
  var self = this;
  self.user = "Will"
  self.customers = ['will','tom'];

  SocketFactory.on('queue', function(queue){
    console.log(queue)
    self.customers = queue
  })
}
```

Comment: Yes! It works!! Question - I like using controllerAs and 'this' in controllers rather than $scope. Would this be an indication that's not the best idea?

Comment: Nope.  ControllerAs is becoming a best practice.  I think there are rumors that Angular 2.0 is going to do away with scope altogether.  "this" can be confusing in javascript regardless.